# Compare the same table and ignore results

Tags: sql

Ok, so I have a single table I need to extract data out of.  The table looks like this:

```
ID        CO_ID      Company
123456               ABC Company
5847      123456     Jim Bob Company
524863               John Smith Company
8975                 Suzie Q United
77458     524863     Ha Ha Limited
```

I need to query the table to give me all companies that are not tied to another company or have a company tied to them.  So every company has an ID but only select few have a CO_ID and that is only if they are tied to another company.  I want to pull only companies that have no ties to themselves.  These records all exist in the same table.  I can't seem to figure out how to do the comparison so I get the results I am looking for.

EDIT:  In this example, only 8975 should be returned.  In real life, this table has 3500 records in it.

Thanks.

Jayson

Comment: From the dataset above, should only `8975 Suzie Q` United be returned?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the answer for the data you have given.

Comment: Post edited.  In this example, there is only one returned record.  In real life, this table has 3500 records in it and should have several returned records.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want all rows where `CO_ID` is null and `ID` is not referenced by another row.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT CO_ID FROM table WHERE CO_ID IS NOT NULL)
  AND CO_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Where this is written. You can't assume on your own

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is specifically something the OP does not want.  This will return no rows at all.

Comment: Yeah, this returns no rows at all.

Comment: @Jayson check my query again and try once more. I fixed the null case.

Comment: Ok, I believe I got this to work.  The issue is that the CO_ID is not a null box but a blank box so I had to change the Null calls to <> '' and = ''

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you want this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.CO_ID = t.ID) AND
      CO_ID IS NULL;
```

Note the semantics of `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` are subtly different.  The "equivalent" `NOT IN` query will return no rows because `CO_ID` takes on `NULL` values.

Comment: Keep in mind as well that CO_ID being null doesn't mean the record is good.  CO_ID is just a tie to show that record B is associated with Record A(ID in which CO_ID points to).  I need all record A's that have no CO_ID to them but also where Record A's ID is not referenced by any other record.

Comment: This returns no rows at all.

Comment: @Jayson . . . Oops, a typo in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT id, company FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT co_id FROM table WHERE co_id IS NOT NULL)
AND co_id IS NULL;
```

If the blank entries are ' ' (single space), then this becomes

```
SELECT id, company FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT co_id FROM table WHERE co_id != ' ')
AND co_id = ' ';
```

and if they are '' (empty string), use that

Comment: Are the blank entries in the `col_id` column NULLs or blanks (empty strings or  spaces)? Change "IS NOT NULL" above accordingly -- it works on the example you provided.

Comment: Got it.  Not Nulls and sorry to not include that in my original request.